# Custom conversion of Apache Kafka header using Spring Kafka

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am using Spring Boot 2.3.0 with Spring Kafka 2.5.0 in in my KafkaListener I am trying to map  to map of the MessageHeaders to a custom class. The code below works, but gives me the header in byte[] that I would then have to convert to the class inside the listener (and repeat that for every listener), which I would like to avoid.

```
    @Slf4j
    @Component
    @KafkaListener(topics = {"${spring.kafka.topics.simple}"}, groupId = "consumerGroup", 
    containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
    public class RequestConsumer {

       @KafkaHandler
       public void listen(@Payload CustomerDetails customerDetails, @Header("sec") byte[] 
       principle, @Headers MessageHeaders messageHeaders) {
           log.info("Received a CustomerDetails");
       }

       @KafkaHandler(isDefault = true)
       public void listen(@Payload(required = false) GenericRecord object, @Headers 
       MessageHeaders messageHeaders) {
           log.info("Received an unexpected object");
       }
    }
```

THe moment i change the code to this:

```
    @KafkaHandler
    public void listen(@Payload CustomerDetails customerDetails, @Header("sec") PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken principle, @Headers MessageHeaders messageHeaders) {
        log.info("Received a CustomerDetails");
    }
```

The listener will break with this error:

org.springframework.kafka.listener.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener method 'public void com.example.demo.consumer.RequestConsumer.listen(com.example.schemas.CustomerDetails,org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken,org.springframework.messaging.MessageHeaders)' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [byte[]] to type [@org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.Header org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken]; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [byte[]] to type [@org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.Header org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken]

I've looked over the https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#headers documentation which talks about header mapping from Headers to MessageHeaders and vise versa, but has no examples of converting those headers. The error seems to suggest that I can register a convertor somehow, but have not found out how despite many Google searches and trying to step through the code of Spring Kafka.

Help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,
Oskar

Answer (score 0):

I kept at it, and I found a proper way to implement this. While I did not find a way to convert the header, it's possible write a handlerMethodArgumentResolver that allows us to use custom objects in listeners. Inside this code it's easy to convert the header to a PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken object which I can then use in the listener directly.

More details: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.5.3.RELEASE/reference/html/#adding-custom-handlermethodargumentresolver-to-kafkalistener

Validated to be working.

Cheers.

Comment: The `DefaultKafkaHeaderMapper` can decode headers from JSON if Jackson is on the classpath. If the source application is also Spring, it sets up a special header `spring_json_header_types` which is a JSON map of header name to types. If the source is not Spring, you would need to either set up the special header or customize the header mapper to understand what type to convert your header to.